# Modal popup search window to replace dropdown control ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, search, popup, modal-dialog, lookup

I'm looking for the simplest way of popping a modal search window on top of an ASP.NET 3.5 application to look up values for a field. I've got a screen for users to add courses; users need to be able to choose an instructor by searching for instructors in a popup.

So - the popup would have a textbox and a gridview with results; clicking the "choose" button in a result would populate the instructor field on the calling form.

What's the simplest way to achieve this?

Comment: check my answer, it does exactly what you were describing

Answer (score 1):

Try using jQuery inside a UserControl with something like the tutorial from [yensdesign](http://yensdesign.com/2008/09/how-to-create-a-stunning-and-smooth-popup-using-jquery/).

The UserControl I created with this approach provided the user the option to set their preferences for the site. I found with this approach it was easier to control the interaction between the modal window and the calling window than calling a new popup browser window. One also doesn't have to worry about popup blockers getting in the way.

Is this helpful or are you looking for more detail?

Comment: So the popup is not a separate window; it's a usercontrol embedded in the parent page?

Comment: Yes, it's a hidden user control that is displayed over the page when appropriate. This is harder technically than using window.open though.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple approach would be to add javascript to your page to popup a new browser window dialog, something like this:

```
function fnFieldSearch(searchURL)
{
    var wndSearch = window.open(searchURL,"SearchPopup","toolbar=yes,width=600,height=400,directories=no,status=yes,scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes,menubar=no");
    wndSearch.focus();
}
```

On the modal search page, use javascript to send the search value back:

```
window.opener.document.FormName.ControlName.value = 'whatever';
```